# What necessary code should i have typed in?

Tags: r

I am doing a reclassification of my old variables to a new set. I tried running the code but Rstudio is telling me that there is something wrong with my code which i cant see from my end. How do i correct this?

This image explains what i am asking about.

[image: img]

Comment: If a name contains a `-`, you need to put quotation marks around it.

Comment: @Roland, i have tried that, but its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Roland's answer is good. You can also use a _ instead of - when renaming.
However, to make it easier to answer your questions, you should copy and paste a reproducible chunk of code, and copy and paste the error message, not a hard-to-read screenshot. Good luck.

Comment: This is the code i run: rel=revalue(proj3$relationship, c(Husband ='Huswife',Wife ='Huswife','Not_in_family' = 'Other',Other-relative ='Other', Own-child ='Other',Unmarried ='Other'))  and this the output message i get; rror: unexpected '=' in "rel=revalue(proj3$relationship, c(Husband ='Huswife',Wife ='Huswife','Not_in_family' = 'Other',Other-relative =

Comment: i have tried making some changes in my line of code, but this time, i get the output  as ''The following `from` values were not present in `x`: Not_in_family, Other_relative, Own_child''.   However, i am made to belief that i have not missed any variable in there.

Comment: It's not really possible to help you without knowing what you did leading up to the error. Could you post a mock example of your code so we can run it and see where the issue might be? A good example looks like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65006467/matching-based-on-different-independent-tables-using-data-table-in-r