# Matching based on different independent tables using data.table in R

Tags: r, join, data.table, matching

I would like to match multiple conditions from independent data tables onto my main data table.
How can I do this using the `data.table` package?
What would be the most efficient/fastest way?

I have a mock example, with some mock conditions here to illustrate my question:

```
main_data <- data.frame( pnum = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                         age = c(24,35,43,34,55,24,36,43,34,54),
                         gender = c("f","m","f","f","m","f","m","f","f","m"))

data_1 <- data.frame( pnum = c(1,4,5,8,9),
                      value_data_1 = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1),
                      date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2018-07-01", "2018-01-01", "2016-07-01", "2016-07-01")))

data_2 <- data.frame( pnum = c(1,5,7,8,9),
                      value_data_2 = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2),
                      date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2018-07-01", "2018-01-01", "2016-07-01", "2016-07-01")))
```

I would like to create a new variable in my main_data table called "matching" of those rows that match between data_1 and data_2 under multiple conditions:

- First, the value of data_1$value_data_1 has to be equal to 1.
- Second, the value of data_2$value_data_2 also has to be equal to 1.
- Third, the pnum and the date should match between data_1 and data_2.

When all these conditions are met, I would expect the new output of main_data to look like this:

```
> main_data
   pnum age gender matching
1     1  24      f        1
2     2  35      m        0
3     3  43      f        0
4     4  34      f        0
5     5  55      m        0
6     6  24      f        0
7     7  36      m        0
8     8  43      f        1
9     9  34      f        0
10   10  54      m        0
```

Until now, I programmed each condition seperately and created new placeholder tables in between, but this is not very memory efficient. Is there an efficient way to chain all the conditions using the `data.tables` package specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
setDT(main_data)
setDT(data_1)
setDT(data_2)

main_data %>%
  data_1[., on = .(pnum == pnum) ] %>%
  data_2[., on = .(pnum == pnum, date == date) ] %>%
  .[, matching := fcoalesce(+(value_data_1 == 1 & value_data_2 == 1), 0L) ] %>%
  .[, .(pnum, age, gender, matching) ]
#     pnum age gender matching
#  1:    1  24      f        1
#  2:    2  35      m        0
#  3:    3  43      f        0
#  4:    4  34      f        0
#  5:    5  55      m        0
#  6:    6  24      f        0
#  7:    7  36      m        0
#  8:    8  43      f        1
#  9:    9  34      f        0
# 10:   10  54      m        0
```

I used the `magrittr` package because I find it useful for portraying the flow code. It is not at all required, and the alternative pipeline for `data.table` for the same code could be:

```r
data_2[
  data_1[main_data, on = .(pnum == pnum) ]
 ,on = .(pnum == pnum, date == date)
][ ,matching := fcoalesce(+(value_data_1 == 1 & value_data_2 == 1), 0L)
  ][ ,.(pnum, age, gender, matching) ]
```

There are other ways to break it out, including the use of temporary (mid-step) variables. (This is mostly style and personal preference.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like `Reduce(merge, list(...))`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(main_data); setDT(data_1); setDT(data_2)

res <- Reduce(function(x, y) {
  merge(x, y, by = "pnum", all.x = TRUE)
}, list(main_data, data_1[, -"date"], data_2[, -"date"]))[, `:=`(
  matching = 1L - (value_data_1 != 1 | value_data_2 != 1 | is.na(value_data_1) | is.na(value_data_2)), 
  value_data_1 = NULL,
  value_data_2 = NULL
)]
```

Output

```
> res[]
    pnum age gender matching
 1:    1  24      f        1
 2:    2  35      m        0
 3:    3  43      f        0
 4:    4  34      f        0
 5:    5  55      m        0
 6:    6  24      f        0
 7:    7  36      m        0
 8:    8  43      f        1
 9:    9  34      f        0
10:   10  54      m        0
```

Comment: This should be easier after https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4370